# Express.JS net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH for static file

Tags: node.js, http, express

I'm not able to charge one static file over express.js. Sometime, it work, sometime not.

The error i get is net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH

Please understand that i use proxy but the error is occuring too when i was trying the request directly to the server.

So i have to reload the page several time, and sometime, it work

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing the same issue. it seems to be related to chrome/chromium only. Have you tried with other browsers? ps what version of nodejs are you using?

Comment: probably its an issue related to nodejs since version 8.0
have a look here: https://github.com/expressjs/express/issues/3392
I'm going to try to upgrade node and if it doesnt work i'd set server.keepAliveTimeout = 60000 * 2;

Comment: Well, i'm using node v6.10.3. And i tried with Mozilla too, and i don't remembered that it solved the problem.
I set the keepAliveTimeout, hoping this will work good